# What is the purpose of having a function prototype in a function?

Tags: c++, c

I will admit I have not kept up with the latest C/C++ releases but I was wondering why having a function prototype in a function is valid code? Is it related to lambda usage?

Here is sample code - this will compile/run on Visual Studio 2019 and g++ 5.4.0

```c
int main()
{
    int func(bool test);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is unchanged from very old versions of C.

Comment: Reason for declaring a function inside a block are the same as reasons for declaring other things inside a block—it limits scope, which limits opportunities for mistakes caused by accidentally using a thing where it is not needed or wanted.

Comment: @o11c the sample code I provided does not compile in older versions of Visual Studio (such as 2015) and gcc 4.8.1. Does gcc require a special flag to compile it?

Comment: Compiles for me using x86-64 gcc 4.8.1 at godbolt.org both as C++ and as C. (For C, you do need to include stdbool.h)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A code block may contain any number of declarations.  And because a function prototype is a declaration, it may appear in a block.

Granted, it doesn't make much sense to do so logistically as opposed to declaring a function at file scope, but it's syntactically correct.

Comment: I've never had a good reason for a function declaration that's scoped by a function, but who knows? Lot of stuff I've never seen before out there.

Comment: @user4581301 originally it was meant for "open parameter list" functions in C, because  "void (*)();" in C can be type of function taking any arguments. Calling conventions allowed to have flexible parameters lists, like variadic functions. Imagine that in one particular case you need call it in only certain way, but in another within other block.  In C++ such prototypes are pretty useless, variable parameter list is limited to variadic syntax. But in C++ you can declare types, classes and function prototypes within a function block.

Answer (score 2):

In that example the declaration is pointless. But in a more complex example it's not:

```
int main() {
    int func(bool test);
    func(true);
    return 0;
}
```

That code is equivalent to the more usual formulation:

```
int func(bool test);

int main() {
    int func(bool test);
    func(true);
    return 0;
}
```

except that the first one introduces the name `func` **only** inside the scope of `main`; the second one introduces the name into the global scope.

I occasionally use the first form when I don't want to scroll through the source file to figure out where to put the declaration; putting it in the function where it's going to be used is a quick-and-dirty solution. And if it's temporary code (adding debugging output, for example), it makes it easier to remove it all afterwards. But, in general, having declarations at global scope is simpler to deal with. After all, you might want to call that same function from somewhere else, too, and having the global declaration means you don't have to repeat it.